# How to use Delta with Spark 3.0 Preview?

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

SPARK 3.0 not able to save a DF as delta table in HDFS

- Scala version 2.12.10
- Spark version 3.0 Preview

Able to do it in 2.4.4 but partition is not getting created.

Input sample:

```
Vehicle_id|model|brand|year|miles|intake_date_time

v0001H|verna|Hyundai|2011|5000|2018-01-20 06:30:00

v0001F|Eco-sport|Ford|2013|4000|2018-02-10 06:30:00

v0002F|Endeavour|Ford|2011|8000|2018-04-12 06:30:00

v0001L|Gallardo|Lambhorghini|2013|2000|2018-05-16 06:30:00
```

```
// reading 
val deltaTableInput1 = spark.read
                            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                            .option("header","true")
                            .option("delimiter","|")
                            .option("inferSchema","true")
                            .load("file")
                            .selectExpr("Vehicle_id","model","brand","year","month","miles","CAST(concat(substring(intake_date_time,7,4),concat(substring(intake_date_time,3,4),concat(substring(intake_date_time,1,2),substring(intake_date_time,11,9)))) AS TIMESTAMP) as intake_date_time")  

// Writing
 deltaTableInput1.write
                 .mode("overwrite")
                 .partitionBy("brand","model","year","month")
                 .format("delta")
                 .save("path")
```

ERROR:

> com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:714)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:676)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:124)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:71)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:69)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:87)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:189)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:227)
>          at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:224)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:185)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:110)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:109)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:829)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:829)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:309)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:236)
>          ... 47 elided
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.LogStoreProvider.createLogStore(LogStore.scala:122)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.LogStoreProvider.createLogStore$(LogStore.scala:120)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.createLogStore(DeltaLog.scala:58)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.LogStoreProvider.createLogStore(LogStore.scala:117)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.LogStoreProvider.createLogStore$(LogStore.scala:115)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.createLogStore(DeltaLog.scala:58)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.(DeltaLog.scala:79)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.$anonfun$call$2(DeltaLog.scala:718)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.$anonfun$call$1(DeltaLog.scala:718)
>          at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksLogging.scala:77)
>          at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation$(DatabricksLogging.scala:67)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordOperation(DeltaLog.scala:645)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:103)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:89)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLog.scala:645)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.call(DeltaLog.scala:717)
>          at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.call(DeltaLog.scala:714)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
>          at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
>          ... 71 more

In Spark 2.4.4 from REPL it's getting written without partitioning.

Spark 3.0 error

Comment: How are you executing the code? Via `spark-submit` or via `java -jar`? What is the value of `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: What's the version of delta lake? Is this 0.4.0 or perhaps a build from the master?

Comment: spark-shell, running in spark shell

Comment: compile group: 'io.delta', name: 'delta-core_2.12', version: '0.4.0'  - delta version

Comment: Since Spark 3.0 hasn't been released yet, whatever happens with Delta with any 3.0 previews could only be considered a bug not something worth a question on StackOverflow. Closing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about unreleased version of Spark and as such seems more a bug to be reported in a JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

Found on [slack](https://delta-users.slack.com/archives/CJ70UCSHM/p1576536580023200):

> Spark 3.0 is significantly different than Spark 2.4, therefore it won't work
>
> There is a branch though? https://github.com/delta-io/delta/tree/spark-3.0-snapshot

Comment: delta-core supporting Spark 3.0 is not deployed to Maven Repo yet ?

Comment: It is. Just today.

Comment: cant find it here though : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core . I am trying to build the artifacts from delta-lake master branch.

Comment: Looks like mvnreposity got stalled? https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.delta/delta-core_2.12